# Why won't location detection with navigator work with iOS 10?

Tags: javascript, ios, gps, geolocation, navigator

Please reference the below links for examples. When attempting to use the [w3 school tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_nav_geolocation) with iOS 10, we are receiving an error when trying to get a users location.

This tutorial works fine in previous versions of iOS. Can anyone explain what the difference is between versions and what we could do to fix it?

Comment: 1. w3schools is bad 2. what error exactly? 3. which browser?

Comment: The w3 schools was just an easy way to demonstrate the problem i'm running into. The error says: "Unable to detect location. Ensure location services are enabled on your device." Location services are enabled on my device and I have registered the proper location strings in my apps info.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know exactly without seeing the error message. However, in iOS 10, you now have to explicitly specify that you want to access the user's location in your .plist file.

See the docs here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW18

> Important: To protect user privacy, an iOS app linked on or after iOS 10.0, and which accesses the user’s location information, must statically declare the intent to do so. Include the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key in your app’s Info.plist file and provide a purpose string for this key. If your app attempts to access the user’s location information without a corresponding purpose string, your app exits.

Comment: Hi knt, thanks for the answer, I have registered both NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key and the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key with an appropriate string and still the navigator geocodeservice is unable to access the devices location.